# clojure - contains?, conj and recur

Tags: clojure, tail-recursion

I'm trying to write a function with recur that cut the sequence as soon as it encounters a repetition (`[1 2 3 1 4]` should return `[1 2 3]`), this is my function:

```
(defn cut-at-repetition [a-seq] 
  (loop[[head & tail] a-seq, coll '()]
    (if (empty? head)
      coll
      (if (contains? coll head)
        coll
        (recur (rest tail) (conj coll head))))))
```

The first problem is with the `contains?` that throws an exception, I tried replacing it with `some` but with no success. The second problem is in the `recur` part which will also throw an exception

Comment: `contains?` checks, if a key is in e.g. a set or map.  it also can be used on array/vectors to check if an _index_ is there.  it's not supported on seqs.  also `head` there is a value from your `a-seq` (the first one) - and `empty?` is for checking, if a list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made several mistakes:

- You've used `contains?` on a sequence. It only works on associative
  collections. Use `some` instead.
- You've tested the first element of the sequence (`head`) for `empty?`. 
  Test the whole sequence.
- Use a vector to accumulate the answer. `conj` adds elements to the
  front of a list, reversing the answer.

Correcting these, we get

```
(defn cut-at-repetition [a-seq] 
  (loop [[head & tail :as all] a-seq, coll []]
    (if (empty? all)
      coll
      (if (some #(= head %) coll)
        coll
        (recur tail (conj coll head))))))

(cut-at-repetition [1 2 3 1 4])
=> [1 2 3]
```

---

The above works, but it's slow, since it scans the whole sequence for every absent element. So better use a set.

Let's call the function `take-distinct`, since it is similar to `take-while`. If we follow that precedent and make it lazy, we can do it thus:

```
(defn take-distinct [coll]
  (letfn [(td [seen unseen]
              (lazy-seq
                (when-let [[x & xs] (seq unseen)]
                  (when-not (contains? seen x)
                    (cons x (td (conj seen x) xs))))))]
    (td #{} coll)))
```

We get the expected results for finite sequences:

```
(map (juxt identity take-distinct) [[] (range 5) [2 3 2]]
=> ([[] nil] [(0 1 2 3 4) (0 1 2 3 4)] [[2 3 2] (2 3)])
```

And we can take as much as we need from an endless result:

```
(take 10 (take-distinct (range)))
=> (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

I would call your eager version `take-distinctv`, on the `map` -> `mapv` precedent. And I'd do it this way:

```
(defn take-distinctv [coll]
  (loop [seen-vec [], seen-set #{}, unseen coll]
    (if-let [[x & xs] (seq unseen)]
      (if (contains? seen-set x)
        seen-vec
        (recur (conj seen-vec x) (conj seen-set x) xs))
      seen-vec)))
```

Notice that we carry the seen elements twice:

- as a vector, to return as the solution; and
- as a set, to test for membership of.

---

Two of the three mistakes were commented on by @cfrick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tradeoff between saving a line or two and making the logic as simple & explicit as possible. To make it as obvious as possible, I would do it something like this:

```
(defn cut-at-repetition
  [values]
  (loop [remaining-values values
         result           []]
    (if (empty? remaining-values)
      result
      (let [found-values (into #{} result)
            new-value    (first remaining-values)]
        (if (contains? found-values new-value)
          result
          (recur
            (rest remaining-values)
            (conj result new-value)))))))

(cut-at-repetition [1 2 3 1 4]) => [1 2 3]
```

Also, be sure to bookmark [The Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html) and always keep a browser tab open to it.

Comment: Building a brand new set each iteration is very expensive, and it would be just as easy to build it incrementally.

Comment: Yes, but since it is for instructional purposes I wanted to avoid having both `result` and `found-values` in the `loop-recur`.

Comment: ... then you might as well test the elements as you go along, instead of accumulating a set to test with.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to hear feedback on this utility function which I wrote for myself (uses `filter` with stateful `pred` instead of a `loop`):

```
(defn my-distinct
  "Returns distinct values from a seq, as defined by id-getter."
  [id-getter coll]
  (let [seen-ids (volatile! #{})
        seen?    (fn [id] (if-not (contains? @seen-ids id)
                            (vswap! seen-ids conj id)))]
    (filter (comp seen? id-getter) coll)))

(my-distinct identity "abracadabra")
; (\a \b \r \c \d)

(->> (for [i (range 50)] {:id (mod (* i i) 21) :value i})
     (my-distinct :id)
     pprint)

; ({:id  0, :value 0}
;  {:id  1, :value 1}
;  {:id  4, :value 2}
;  {:id  9, :value 3}
;  {:id 16, :value 4}
;  {:id 15, :value 6}
;  {:id  7, :value 7}
;  {:id 18, :value 9})
```

Docs of [filter](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/filter) says "pred must be free of side-effects" but I'm not sure if it is ok in this case. Is `filter` guaranteed to iterate over the sequence in order and not for example take skips forward?

Comment: I think `filter` wants `pred` to be free of side-effects to prevent chunking causing surprises.

Comment: I thought so too. If `filter` happens to use multi-threading then this construction is inherently dangerous. :/ In that case `atom` would be more appropriate.