# split an array in multiple arrays based in a value

Tags: clojure

I need to separate a array of objects in multiple arrays, based on a exactly value of each one. IE.

```
[
  {"15/02" :date},
  {"16/02" :date},
  {"15/02" :date},
]
```

result should be:

```
  [
      [
        {"15/02" :date},
        {"15/02" :date}
      ],
      [
        {"16/02" :date}
      ]
  ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clojure - contains?, conj and recur](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839639/clojure-contains-conj-and-recur)

Comment: No, because i need to both objects inside by vector, I don't wanna merge then

Comment: why do you have maps that appear to have key and value swapped?

Answer (score 2):

This will produce the answer you are looking for:

```
(mapv val (group-by ffirst dates))
```

A (hash)map is a `sequable?` of map-entries. Here the *object* we are after is the first map-entry (of always one only), which is represented as a tuple (2-vector) in Clojure, for example `["15/02" :date]`. From that object we need to be grouping by the first (key of the map-entry) element of the tuple. Hopefully that explains why `ffirst` works to get the string key that needs to be the subject of `group-by`.

Comment: Please note, that `first` and `second` for map entries works, but gives not proper intent.  So rather than `second` i'd use `val` instead.  The `ffirst` there is even trickier.  So instead of the "inner" `first` `key` would be better, but the "outer" `first` only works here because of the shape of the data.  If that map has more entries, this will fail as maps only appear ordered for the first few pairs.  For the example `(map val (group-by identity data))` would be enough.

Comment: I've always assumed that `:date` really meant an actual date, so the vals varied, so identity wouldn't be the right thing. Point taken about there only being one - but I stressed that and am (in this case) working with the data given. So `(mapv val (group-by (comp key first) dates))` would be an alternative, but I'll just change `val`.

Comment: Yeah the shape of the example data is odd.   Either it's key/value swapped or if `:date` really is a stand-in for any date, then a `(group-by extract-day date-list)` would be better in the first place

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**

The data doesn't look right.

- Each of the maps inside the vector has a single entry, and might as
  well be an ordered pair.
- If these are cut-down records, surely the keys and values are the
  wrong way round, and should be

`(def data [{:date "15/02"} {:date "16/02"} {:date "15/02"}])`.

Then a solution is

```
(->> data (group-by :date) vals vec)
=> [[{:date "15/02"} {:date "15/02"}] [{:date "16/02"}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading you comment, I see it is not a duplicate.

You can get all of the hard work done with the `frequencies` function.  Please see:

- [The Clojure Cheatsheet](http://jafingerhut.github.io/cheatsheet/clojuredocs/cheatsheet-tiptip-cdocs-summary.html)
- [ClojureDocs.org](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies)

Here is the code in action:

```
(def data [
           {"15/02" :date},
           {"16/02" :date},
           {"15/02" :date},
          ])

(frequencies data) => { {"15/02" :date} 2, 
                        {"16/02" :date} 1}
```

So the result is a Clojure map where the keys are the original (unique) values and the vals are the count of the occurrance of each value.

We can add a little code to repeat each unique value the correct number of times to get your final result:

```
(defn make-repeat-groups
  [freq-map]
  (vec
    (for [entry freq-map]
      (let [ [item reps] entry]
        (vec (repeat reps item))))))

(make-repeat-groups (frequencies data)) 
  =>  [ [{"15/02" :date} 
         {"15/02" :date}] 
        [{"16/02" :date}] ]
```

Note that you don't really need the two `vec` functions, but I think the output is a bit easier to read if it is a vector instead of a (lazy) list.